# Openldap restrict inter database access

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have created 2 below databases in `OpenLDAP.`

```
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=testdomain1,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=testdomain1,dc=com"
rootpw      secret
directory   /usr/local/var/openldap-testdomain1


database    bdb
suffix      "dc=testdomain1,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=testdomain2,dc=com"
rootpw      secret
directory   /usr/local/var/openldap-testdomain2
```

But I can access both databases with Bind Account credentials`(cn=Manager,dc=testdomain1,dc=com)` from domain 1. Can anyone suggest me a solution to restrict access to users from same domain only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in openldap documentation.
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html

I added below lines in my `slapd.conf` file

```
access to dn.subtree="dc=testdomain1,dc=com"
    by self write
    by dn.children="dc=testdomain1,dc=com" search
    by anonymous auth

access to dn.subtree="dc=testdomain2,dc=com"
    by self write
    by dn.children="dc=testdomain2,dc=com" search
    by anonymous auth
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the Manager account for anything. **Anything.** Period. It is for OpenLDAP itself, and it bypasses a whole lot of processing you don't want to bypass, such as the password-policy overlay.

You should define your own administrative accounts, and accounts for the applications and users that are going to login to it, and give them access control as per *man slapd.conf*.